# What is causing the following contradiction which calculating the limit?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_n$ be a positive sequence.

We define $b_n$ as the following:

$$b_n = a_1/a_2 + a_2/a_3 + ... + a_{n-1}/a_n$$

Then does that mean $b_n$ converges to infinity?

---

**On the one hand:**

$$b_n/n = (a_1/a_2 + a_2/a_3 + ... + a_{n-1}/a_n)/n >= (a_1/a_n)^{1/n}$$
which means:
$$b_n>n*(a_1/a_n)^{1/n}$$ the right side converges to infinity and so the left one

**On the other hand,** if we take b_n to be 1+1/2+1/4+1/8 (By choosing $a_n={1,2,8,64...}$)then it is known that it converges to infinite number which contradicts the previous result.

Comment: Certainly some conditions must be attached to $(a_n)$. For some sequence $(a_n)$, the sequence $(b_n)$ may converge, for some other it may diverge. In fact, whatever sequence $(b_n)$ you prescribe (with some loose conditions, e.g. $b_n>0$), and choosing arbitrary $a_1$, you can reverse-engineer it to find the sequence $(a_n)$  that would yield your chosen sequence $(b_n)$... proving that the sequence $(b_n)$ can end up being pretty much anything you want.

Comment: Your claim that $n*(a_1/a_n)^{1/n}$ always diverges to infinity is wrong, as your own example shows.

Comment: @MartinR why? a1/an is positive number then (1/)1/  converges to 1 for sure...

Comment: It is not a fixed number but also depend on on. What if $a_n$ grows very fast?

Comment: @StinkingBishop then  (1/)1/ is 2 which doesn't prove I'm wrong

Comment: @MartinR what do u mean if it grows too fast? can u give a contradict example...

Comment: You gave the counter example yourself: $a_n = 1, 2, 8, 64, \ldots = 2^{n(n-1)/2}$

Comment: @dan Sorry, my bad... I meant can you make e.g. $(a_1/a_n)^{1/n}=1/n$? You can solve this for $a_n$ to get $a_n=\frac{a_1}{(1/n)^n}=a_1n^n$. My point still stands - pick $b_n$ whatever you want and you can craft $a_n$'s to produce those $b_n$'s - thus the original problem must've had some condition on $(a_n)$ that you did not write in your question.